# Merge two dataframes and create multiple columns in R

Tags: r, merge

Suppose that we have two data frames as shown below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Team1 = c("A","B","C"), Team2 = c("D","E","F"), Winner = c("A","E","F"))

df2 <- data.frame(Country = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), Index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

What i want is create three columns in df2 as Team1_index, Team2_index, and Winner_index.

```
Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
A     D      A           1           4            1
B     E      E           2           5            5
C     F      F           3           6            6
```

I tried many ways but failed. Tips and advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a small number of columns, you can use the match function as in the example:

```
df1$Team1_index <- df2$Index[match(df1$Team1, df2$Country)]
df1$Team2_index <- df2$Index[match(df1$Team2, df2$Country)]
df1$Winner_index <- df2$Index[match(df1$Winner, df2$Country)]
df1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more columns, you may look for more systematic solutions, but if it's really just three cases, this should do:

```
library("tidyverse")
df1 <- data.frame(Team1 = c("A","B","C"), Team2 = c("D","E","F"), Winner = c("A","E","F"))
df2 <- data.frame(Country = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), Index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% rename(Team1 = Country), by = "Team1") %>% 
  rename(Team1_Index = Index) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% rename(Team2 = Country), by = "Team2") %>% 
  rename(Team2_Index = Index) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% rename(Winner = Country), by = "Winner") %>% 
  rename(Winner_Index = Index) 
#> Warning: Column `Team1` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#> Warning: Column `Team2` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#> Warning: Column `Winner` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#>   Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_Index Team2_Index Winner_Index
#> 1     A     D      A           1           4            1
#> 2     B     E      E           2           5            5
#> 3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

You can safely ignore the warnings.

Comment: The easy way out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get new columns as factors :

```
df1[paste0(colnames(df1),"_index")] <- lapply(df1,factor,df2$Country,df2$Index)
#   Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
# 1     A     D      A           1           4            1
# 2     B     E      E           2           5            5
# 3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

To get new columns as numeric :

```
df1[paste0(colnames(df1),"_index")] <-
  lapply(df1,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(factor(x,df2$Country,df2$Index))))
#   Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
# 1     A     D      A           1           4            1
# 2     B     E      E           2           5            5
# 3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

Note that for this specific case (index from 1 incremented by 1), this shorter version works:

```
df1[paste0(colnames(df1),"_index")] <-
  lapply(df1,function(x) as.numeric(factor(x,df2$Country)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for you that uses `match` and `cbind`.

```
df3 <- as.matrix(df1)
colnames(df3) <- paste0(colnames(df3), "_index")

# match the positions
df3[] <- match(df3, df2$Country)
cbind(df1, df3)
#  Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
#1     A     D      A           1           4            1
#2     B     E      E           2           5            5
#3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

`df3` is created as a matrix, i.e. a vector with dimensions attribute, such that we can replace its entries with the result of `match` (a vector) right away and don't need to repeat the code for every column.

Or in one go

```
df1[paste0(colnames(df1), "_index")] <- match(as.matrix(df1), df2$Country)
```

Note however, that this ignores the `index` column of `df2`.

---

Thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper we could also write this more general as

```
df1[paste0(colnames(df1), "_index")] <- lapply(df1, function(x) df2$Index[match(x, df2$Country)])
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you.

Comment: can be rewritten as `df1[paste0(colnames(df3), "_index")] <- lapply(df1,match,df2$Country)`, but the column Index is ignored, values are just assumed to be equal to row number

Comment: This would give a general solution : `df1[paste0(colnames(df3), "_index")] <- lapply(df1,function(x) df2$Index[match(x,df2$Country)])`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for your useful comments. (Just the `df3` should be `df1`)

Answer (score 0):

I have an almost solution with data.table, using `melt` and `dacst` to change shape

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.table(Team1 = c("A","B","C"), Team2 = c("D","E","F"), Winner = c("A","E","F")) 
df2 <- data.table(Country = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), Index = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

melt(data = df1 , id.vars = )
plouf <- merge(df2,melt(df1,measure = 1:2), by.x = "Country", by.y = "value")
plouf[,winneridx := Index[Country == Winner]]
dcast(plouf,Country+winneridx~variable,value.var = "Index")


   Country winneridx Team1 Team2
1:       A         1     1    NA
2:       B         5     2    NA
3:       C         6     3    NA
4:       D         1    NA     4
5:       E         5    NA     5
6:       F         6    NA     6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as giocomai's answer, just uses `purrr` to help eliminate duplication:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

getIndexCols <- function(df1, df2, colName){
     idxColName <- sym(paste0(colName, "_Index"))
     df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% rename(!! sym(colName) := Country, !! idxColName := Index))
}


names(df1) %>% purrr::map(~ getIndexCols(df1, df2, .)) %>% reduce(~ left_join(.x, .y))
```

Comment: Complex simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chartr` This will take into consideration both the country column and the index column:

```
df3=as.matrix(setNames(df1,paste0(names(df1),"_index")))

cbind(df1,chartr(paste0(df2$Country,collapse=""),paste0(df2$Index,collapse=""),df3))

  Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
1     A     D      A           1           4            1
2     B     E      E           2           5            5
3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

you can also do:

```
cbind(df1,do.call(chartr,c(as.list(sapply(unname(df2),paste,collapse="")),list(df3))))

  Team1 Team2 Winner Team1_index Team2_index Winner_index
1     A     D      A           1           4            1
2     B     E      E           2           5            5
3     C     F      F           3           6            6
```

Comment: This stores the index columns as factors